# Timezone handling in browser

Tags: angularjs, datetime, angularjs-directive, timezone, datetimepicker

I have a server running in UTC and user's in various timezones interact with the server scheduling various tasks i.e. setting startDate and endDate (along with time values).
Server keeps record of user's home timezone.

Scenario:
User registers on the portal with timezone set to "America/Los_Angeles".
user schedules a task to be initiated at 11:30AM 25-Jan-2015 (say). This has to be a date-time picker.

Requirement 1: The date-time picker should show dates and time as per user's home timezone.
Requirement 2: User might have logged in from a different location let's say Kolkata/India,
Even for this case all the date-time values on screen should be shown in User's home timezone(America/Los_Angeles) and not in browser timezone(Asia/Kolkata).

Comment: you should avoid using native Date object. Native Date object will convert all your UTC time to local machine time. If you want to simulate same timezone for all timezone then you should use some third party library like moment.js, which will give you more power on date object at client side. You can convert you UTC time to user timezone and then you can use it. Or you can override native Date to your custom Date.

Comment: Yes I have considered using moment-timezone for this but none of the available datetime picker have timezone support. They all fallback to Javascript date, so whenever I pass it a moment date with timezone set, it is converted back to browser timzone.

any pointers to an existing javascript libarary preferably and angular directive.

Comment: strip off the timezone information, so that browser doesnt converts it. put that logic in $formatter/$parser.

Comment: browser will add local timezone info when constructing date from string